# Derivative of diagonal matrix $\mbox{diag}(X 1_n) $ with respect to $X$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

For a symmetric matrix $X \in \Bbb R^{n\times n}$, let $$f(X) := u^\top \mbox{diag}(X 1_n) v$$ What is the derivative of $f$ with respect to $X$?

$X 1_n$ is the row-wise summation to generate a vector in $\Bbb R^n$

Comment: Summary or summation?

Comment: The title does not match the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\diag#1{\operatorname{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\operatorname{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$The Frobenius product is a concise notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \|A\|^2_F \\
}$$
This is also called the double-dot or double contraction product.

When applied to vectors $(n=\o)$ it reduces to the standard dot product.

The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in a
Frobenius product to be rearranged in many different ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
C:\LR{AB} &= \LR{CB^T}:A \\&= \LR{A^TC}:B \\
}$$
As with the Hadamard product, the matrix on each side of the
multiplication symbol $(:)$ must have exactly the same dimensions.

Let's also introduce the `Diag()` and `diag()` functions. The first transforms its vector argument into a diagonal matrix while the second generates a vector from the main diagonal of its matrix argument.

Let $\odot$ denote the Hadamard product, $\o$ the all-ones vector,
and note the following identities
$$\eqalign{
&\diag{\Diag a} = a = \Diag{a}\,\o \\
&\diag{ab^T} = \LR{a\odot b} = \Diag{a}\,b \\
&\diag{a\o^T} = \LR{a\odot \o} = \Diag{a}\,\o = a \\
\\
}$$

---

Use the above notation to write the objective function, then
calculate its gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi
 &= u^T\Diag{X\o}v \\
 &= uv^T:\Diag{X\o} \\
 &= \diag{uv^T}:{X\o} \\
 &= \LR{u\odot v}\o^T:X \\
\grad{\phi}{X}
 &= \LR{u\odot v}\o^T \\
}$$

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking to use a mask matrix. But this version is simple and straightforward. Nice~